# How to use right-click-and-drag(mouse) and hold-and-drag(touch) feature to trigger action in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

On some desktop browsers, there's a feature called Mouse Gesture. 
If you right click and hold to draw a right-to-left line, browser will go backward as if you use your finger to swipe from right to left.

On Win 10 UWP, how to write a similar feature, while compatible with touch/phone?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a [`GestureRecognizer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241937).

For a complete sample, see the [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/v1.0.7/Samples/BasicInput/cs/5-GestureRecognizer.xaml.cs) in the Microsoft project on GitHub.

Bonus: [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) Built a [samples API concordance](http://oldnewthing.github.io/Windows-universal-samples/) that can help you drill down into the Windows Universal API to find the samples you're looking for.